# use a variable to return a certain instance variable

Tags: python, class, getattr

I'm working in Python and in a class method, I am trying to return an instance variable, but depending on the variable I want to return another instance variable:

```
def someFunction(self, variable):
    return self.variable
```

This is what I am trying to do, but the variable can have different names. This is in a class. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

You are likely looking for attribute access:

```
def someFunction(self, variable):
    return getattr(self, variable)
```